# Is that possible to cancel an event in flex during event propagation?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, event-handling, flash-builder

Is it possible to cancel an event (native or custom) in flex during event propagation?

Comment: -1: Stop asking questions and calm down. You're posting these questions without much thought in between, as well as including grammatical mistakes in your questions.

Comment: Hi Pimgd. I wanna know something exact and that's why i put question. Whats wrong with this ? Kindly let me know.

Comment: I can only follow Pimgd, this question is too short.. add some more information about what you're planning to achieve, show an example, add some extra details - this sort of question you can ask your colleagues who work on the same project that you do - in our case this doesn't mean much.

Comment: This is what I trying to ask? How actually implement it in code ?

Answer (score 2):

event.preventDefault() - Cancels an event's default behavior if that behavior can be canceled.

event.stopImmediatePropagation() - Prevents processing of any event listeners in the current node and any subsequent nodes in the event flow.

event.stopPropagation() - Prevents processing of any event listeners in nodes subsequent to the current node in the event flow.

[source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html)